# AVL Tree gives me O(c^n) instead of O(log n)

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, big-o, avl-tree

I've created an AVLTree in java and the add method should be of O(log n)... However my add method seems to give me a graph of O(c^n) or an exponential graph instead of a logarithmic graph. Here is the graph of running time vs input size:

[image: Running Time vs Input Size]

Can anyone help figure out as to why this happens?

Here is the code for my AVLTree:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import cw1.rs10.lib.IAVLTree;

public class AVLTree<K, V> implements IAVLTree<K, V>
{
    public class Node {
        private K key;
        private ArrayList<V> values;
        private Node left, right;
        private int height;

        public Node(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.values = new ArrayList<V>();
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
            this.height = 0;

            values.add(value);
        }

        public K getKey() {
            return key;
        }
        public void setKey(K key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public ArrayList<V> getValues() {
            return values;
        }
        public void addValue(V value) {
            values.add(value);
        }

        public Node getLeft() {
            return left;
        }
        public Node getRight() {
            return right;
        }

        public void setLeft(Node left) {
            this.left = left;
        }
        public void setRight(Node right) {
            this.right = right;
        }

        public int getHeight() {
            return height;
        }
        public void setHeight(int height) {
            this.height = height;
        }
    }

    private Node rootNode;
    private Comparator<K> comparator;

    //Unused
    public AVLTree() {
    }

    public AVLTree(Comparator<K> comparator) {
        this.rootNode = null;
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    @Override
    public V add(K k, V v) {
        Node n = rootNode = add(k, v, rootNode);
        if(n != null)
            return v;
        else
            return null;
    }
    private Node add(K key, V value, Node node) {
        if(node == null)
            return new Node(key, value);

        if(comparator.compare(key, node.getKey()) < 0) {
            node.setLeft(add(key, value, node.getLeft()));

            if(height(node.getLeft()) - height(node.getRight()) == 2) {
                if(comparator.compare(key, node.getLeft().getKey()) < 0)
                    node = rotateLeft(node);
                else
                    node = doubleRotateLeft(node);
            }
        } else if(comparator.compare(key, node.getKey()) > 0) {
            node.setRight(add(key, value, node.getRight()));

            if(height(node.getRight()) - height(node.getLeft()) == 2) {
                if(comparator.compare(key, node.getRight().getKey()) > 0)
                    node = rotateRight(node);
                else
                    node = doubleRotateRight(node);
            }
        } else {
            //Handle duplicate
            node.getValues().add(value);
        }

        node.setHeight( Math.max(height(node.getLeft()), height(node.getRight())) + 1 );

        return node;
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(K key, V value) throws Exception {
        Node node = rootNode = remove(key, value, rootNode);
        if(node != null)
            return value;
        else
            return null;
    }
    private Node remove(K key, V value, Node node) {
        //If node with key contains one or less values, remove the whole key
        //Else remove value from node with key
        if(node == null) return null;
        else if(comparator.compare(key, node.getKey()) < 0) {
            node.setLeft(remove(key, value, node.getLeft()));

            if(height(node.getLeft()) - height(node.getRight()) == 2) {
                if(comparator.compare(key, node.getLeft().key) < 0)
                    node = rotateLeft(node);
                else
                    node = doubleRotateLeft(node);
            }
        } else if(comparator.compare(key, node.getKey()) > 0) {
            node.setRight(remove(key, value, node.getRight()));

            if(height(node.getRight()) - height(node.getLeft()) == 2) {
                if(comparator.compare(key, node.getRight().key) < 0)
                    node = rotateRight(node);
                else
                    node = doubleRotateRight(node);
            }
        } else {
            if(node.getValues().size() > 1) {
                node.getValues().remove(value);
                return node;
            } else {
                if(node.getLeft() == null && node.getRight() == null)
                    return null;
                if(node.getLeft() == null) return node.getRight();
                if(node.getRight() == null) return node.getLeft();

                Node smallestNode = smallestNode(node.getRight());
                node = smallestNode;
                node.setRight(remove(key, value, node.getRight()));

                return node;
            }
        }
        return node;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<V> find(K key) {
        Node n = search(key, rootNode);
        if(n != null) {
            ArrayList<V> values = n.getValues();
            return values.iterator();
        } else {
            return new ArrayList<V>().iterator();
        }
    }
    private Node search(K key, Node node) {
        while(node != null) {
            if(comparator.compare(key, node.getKey()) < 0)
                node = node.getLeft();
            else if(comparator.compare(key, node.getKey()) > 0)
                node = node.getRight();
            else
                return node;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<V> removeAll(K key) {
        Node n = search(key, rootNode);
        ArrayList<V> values = n.getValues();

        try {
            remove(n.getKey(), null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return values.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<V> listAll() {
        ArrayList<V> entries = new ArrayList<V>();
        listAll(rootNode, entries);
        return entries.iterator();
    }
    private void listAll(Node n, ArrayList<V> entries) {
        if(n != null) {
            listAll(n.getLeft(), entries);
            entries.addAll(n.getValues());
            listAll(n.getRight(), entries);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int height() {
        return height(rootNode);
    }   

    //Custom Methods
    /**
     * A method to test if the tree is logically empty
     * 
     * @return true if empty, false if not
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return rootNode == null;
    }
    /**
     * Logically empties the tree by setting the rootNode to null
     */
    public void empty() {
        rootNode = null;
    }
    public void inOrderTraversal(Node node) {
        if(node != null) {
            inOrderTraversal(node.getLeft());
            System.out.print(node.getKey() + ", ");
            inOrderTraversal(node.getRight());
        }
    }
    public int height(Node node) {
        if(node == null) return -1;
        else return node.height;
    }
    public Node getRootNode() {
        return rootNode;
    }
    public Node smallestNode(Node node) {
        if(node.getLeft() == null)
            return node;
        return smallestNode(node.getLeft());
    }

    private Node rotateLeft(Node node2) {
        Node node1 = node2.getLeft();

        node2.setLeft(node1.getRight());
        node1.setRight(node2);

        node2.setHeight(Math.max(height(node2.getLeft()), height(node2.getRight())) + 1);
        node1.setHeight(Math.max(height(node1.getLeft()), node2.getHeight()) + 1);

        return node1;
    }
    private Node rotateRight(Node node1) {
        Node node2 = node1.getRight();

        node1.setRight(node2.getLeft());
        node2.setLeft(node1);

        node1.setHeight(Math.max(height(node1.getLeft()), height(node1.getRight())) + 1);
        node2.setHeight(Math.max(height(node2.getRight()), node1.getHeight()) + 1);

        return node2;
    }
    private Node doubleRotateLeft(Node node3) {
        node3.setLeft(rotateRight(node3.getLeft()));
        return rotateLeft(node3);
    }
    private Node doubleRotateRight(Node node1) {
        node1.setRight(rotateLeft(node1.getRight()));
        return rotateRight(node1);
    }
}
```

The interface for my AVLTree:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public interface IAVLTree<K,V>
{
    public V add(K k, V v);

    public V remove(K k, V v);

    public Iterator<V> removeAll(K k);

    public Iterator<V> find(K k);

    public Iterator<V> listAll();

    public int height();

}
```

And finally, my testing code:

```
public class AVLTest
{
    private static long startTime, endTime;
    private static int amountOfCommands = 10000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AVLTree<String, Integer> tree = new AVLTree<String, Integer>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        try {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 1; i <= amountOfCommands; i++) {
                String key = "K" + i;
                tree.add(key, i);
            }
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long runningTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Running Time: " + runningTime + "ms\nNo. of Commands: " + amountOfCommands);
    }
}
```

Comment: Big-O notation describes asymptotic bounds. You're measuring on the lower end of the spectrum where other effects such as the cache hierarchy kick in. It might be better to extend your measurements by a few orders of magnitude.

Comment: @the8472 what do you mean by extending my measurements? surely even this way it should still give me a log n running time?

Comment: He is saying that you need to run tests where the size of your tree is sufficiently large; more elements or operations. You need to run many tests to get an accurate measurement. Orders of magnitude being higher powers of whatever base you are considering (e.g. base 2, base 10, etc.)

Comment: @EvanBechtol ahh okay that's fair enough ^ but either way, it should still give me an O(log n) graph anyways? Since an AVL Tree should have O(log n) time for insertions, searches and removals

Comment: The graph you have shown is far from an exponential. Note that the x-axis is logarithmic while the y-axis is linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are measuring it wrong. Your test code measures the time to add *all* of the elements in the tree, instead of just one.

```
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 1; i <= amountOfCommands; i++) {
    String key = "K" + i;
    tree.add(key, i);
}
endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

What you want to measure is the time it takes to add *one* node to the tree as a function of the number of nodes *already in* the tree.

```
for (int i = 1; i < amountOfCommands; i++) { // note the < instead of <=
    String key = "K" + i;
    tree.add(key, i);
}
String key = "K" + amountOfCommands;
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
tree.add(key, amountOfCommands);
endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Of course you can run your test more efficiently if you reuse the same tree for all measurements. I'll leave it to you.